# How to prevent frequent crashes?

Tags: workflow

I am working on an interior scene of a workshop, and for it I've downloaded a lot of models from sites like blendswap etc. I want to create a detailed scene however, due to all the heavy imports, the file keeps crashing. Is there anyway I can reduce the load on the file to continue working on it.

Comment: Have you tried moving parts of the scene to different layers so you're not viewing everything all the time?

Comment: Look for Proxy-objects. They can visually replace complex mesh with cube or conus for example, but render as real mesh.

Comment: when does the crash happen? rendering? animation? simulations?

Comment: @mixrat Thats how I am managing at the moment. Working on different layers.  But it still gives me problems

Comment: @Serge L I can probably try that, but if I have to do it one object at a time, its going to take me a long long time.

Comment: @m.ardito I haven't rendered anything yet. I am still setting up the scene. I think since there are a lot of high poly meshes, its lagging and eventually crashing. I am worried at the end when I have to combine all my layers, its going to be an impossible task.

Comment: have to ask: are you sure your pc is fit to the work you're doing? can you detail specs: how many polygons/vertices? how much ram? os?

Comment: Yes, I am working on an Asus Laptop. It has 16GB RAM. The vertice count as of now in of the most heavy layer is around 9,133,601. The Operating system is Windows 10. I should probably mention that my C drive is almost full. However, all my blender related stuff is on my D drive.